# htaccess and POST requests

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, isapi-rewrite

I'm using ISAPI htaccess rule on my website.

I opened fiddler and saw an ajax post request with content in its body.

then the client got 302 redirect (htaccess rule),

but this second request was sent with no body content.

How can it be?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, per the [W3 Spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) there should be a body unless it is a HEAD request

> The temporary URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the response. Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI(s).

However, there are webservers that do not implement the spec correctly e.g 
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41718, so it could very well be an instance of this

Comment: @EladBenda If you own the client code, then as long as the location header is sent, you can process the 302 i.e. if you own the client then the body is not necessary

Comment: Didn't fully understand you. sorry. if I remove the [R=302] will it work?